# Is it possible to use stdout/stderr as fluentd source?

Tags: fluentd

#### Question:

**Is it possible to use stdout/stderr as fluentd source?**
If not, are there some sort of workaround to implement this?

#### Background:

I have to containerize a NodeJS web server that uses `json-log` as a logging resource.
Since containers are *ephemeral*, I want to extract it's logs for debugging purposes.
To do this, I've decided to use EFK stack.

However, since...

> The philosophy of `json-log` is...
>
> **Write to stdout/err**

I can only get the logs of the web server from stdout.
After going through the fluentd documentation, I didn't find a way to use stdout/stderr as a source.

#### Related question:

[Is it possible to use stdout as a fluentd source to capture specific logs for write to elasticsearch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44811527)
The question has an answer but it is inapplicable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-log#write-to-stdouterr

You can send logs from json-log to syslog.
So you can use [fluent-plugin-syslog](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/in_syslog) to receive logs from json-log, and send them to Fluentd.

Comment: That might work. But currently, I'm curious if it's possible to use a container's stdout/stderr as fluentd source or if there's a workaround to be able to do so. (since not all apps use `json-log`)

Comment: If you use docker, you can run `docker logs -f` and redirect them to the file on the host. And then use [in_tail plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/in_tail) to read logs from Fluentd.

Comment: Or you can use [fluent-cat](https://docs.fluentd.org/deployment/command-line-option#fluent-cat)

Comment: I am not sure what engine you are using, but if you are using Docker an option is to default to json file logging and tail the logs directory. Another option is to configure Docker to use its fluentd logging driver https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/